# ループで二次元配列作成

Tags: python

**キーと値のペアをループして下記のような二次元配列を作成したいです**

[[1,'北海道'][13,'東京'][47,'沖縄']]

---

**試したけれどもうまくいかないコード**

```
results = []
i=0
for item in data:
    results[i][0].append(data.find('areacode').text) //1回目は1
    results[i][1].append(data.find('prefecture').text) //1回目は北海道
    i+=1
print results
```

**表示結果**

> IndexError: list index out of range

---

**Q**
・ループで二次元配列作成するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
・Pythonでは配列という呼び方はしない？ リスト？
・「キーと値のペア」でデータを保つ場合は、辞書を使用するのでしょうか？
・辞書の場合はどう作成？？？

Comment: `data` はどんな感じですか？

Comment: `data.find('areacode').text` としていますけど、これは `item.find('areacode').text` ではないでしょうか（`data.find('prefecture').text` も同様）。その場合は `results = [[item.find('areacode').text, item.find('prefecture').text] for item in data]` などとも書けます。

Comment: そもそもの話としては二次元配列とか関係なく list の動き方が違ってまして，最初の `results[0]` の時点で `IndexError` になります（ javascript や ruby みたいに `a = [] ; a[0] = 3` で値を入れられません）．

Comment: @BLUEPIXY。「data」はrssから取得した'Xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'オブジェクト(?)です。内容はまだよく理解出来ていません

Comment: @Yosh。IndexError についてはてっきりループ絡みのエラーのだと思い込んでいました、お陰で勘違いに気が付きました。コメント内容大変参考になりました！

Comment: @metropolis。コメントいただいた通り「item.find('areacode').text」の書き間違いです。今気が付きました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ・「キーと値のペア」でデータを保つ場合は、辞書を使用するのでしょうか？
>   ・辞書の場合はどう作成？？？

このような場合辞書を使うのが良いです。
例の場合1番目がindex、2番目が都道府県名、のように配列の番号に意味を持ってしまっていますが、
「基本的には」配列の番号に意味を持たせるべきではないと私は考えます。

辞書の場合以下です。

```
results = {}

for item in data:
    results[item.find('areacode').text] = item.find('prefecture').text

print(results)
```

もしくはkeyにフィールドの意味を持たせるのならば
(こうなってくると元のdataそのまま使っても良い気がしますが・・・)

```
results = []

for item in data:
    results.append({'areacode':item.find('areacode').text,
                    'prefecture':item.find('prefecture').text})

print(results)
```

Comment: 期待した通り動作しました。回答を読んで「キーと値のペア」の場合は素直に辞書を使用しようと思いました

Answer (score 2):

dataの中身がよくわからないので、実際に実行して試していませんが、こんな感じでできませんかね。

```
results = []
i=0

for item in data:
    results.append([item.find('areacode').text, item.find('prefecture').text])
    i+=1

print(results)
```

appendの使い方や、配列(リスト)の使い方を間違っているようなので、詳しくはこのあたりを参照ください。
http://www.pythonweb.jp/tutorial/list/index6.html

Comment: 回答いただいた内容を試してみて初めて気が付いたのですが、二次元配列作成後のデータ操作が思った以上に扱いづらかったため、今回の件については辞書を使用していくことに決めました

Answer (score 2):

> ・ループで二次元配列作成するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

dataの要素がどのようなものか分からないですが、例えば

```
results = [[] for _ in range(data)] # 領域を確保しておく
i=0
for item in data:
    results[i].append(item.find('areacode').text)
    results[i].append(item.find('prefecture').text)
    i+=1
print results
```

> ・Pythonでは配列という呼び方はしない？ リスト？

はい。 `results`はリストです。

> ・「キーと値のペア」でデータを保つ場合は、辞書を使用するのでしょうか？

Pythonでは標準で[辞書が用意されて](http://docs.python.jp/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)います。

一般的には場合によるかと思います。（今回の場合はキーの代わりにリストのインデックスが使えるかも知れません。）

> ・辞書の場合はどう作成？？？

`results`を辞書の形で欲しいということであれば

```
results = {} # 空の辞書
i=0
for item in data:
    results[item.find('areacode').text] = item.find('prefecture').text
    i+=1
print results
```

Comment: 組み込んで動作させてみたら、期待した結果を取得することが出来ました

Answer (score -2):

```
results = {item.find('areacode').text:item.find('prefecture').text for item in data}
```

辞書作るだけなら1行でできる。